# Can somebody tell me why i *can* read minecraft server -> client data but not the other way around?

Tags: c++, minecraft

First of all, a big thank you to anyone willing to help!

You can skip the following wall of text if you want.

**Background**

I am trying to make a proxy program for my own minecraft server network. I wish to use multiple servers to allow people to play creative and survival on separate servers (to reduce serverload and increase my capacity). I am planning on using the *transporter plugin* for the server side of things, but I'd like to prevent having to install a *clientpatch*.

I discovered *bungeecord*, but it didn't do what I needed it to (namely, forge support for a modded server I plan on adding.) for mc 1.4.7 (which I need to use due to the server I plan on adding).

At the moment the system is running using a *bungeecord proxy*. However, md_5 told me that I'd need to write my own proxy (or mod his) to make it work the way I want. However, I really can't wrap my head around java (I just don't get it). So I decided to write my own.

**The problem**

After some research I discovered this to be doable. The hardest part would be to parse the packets. So I dug around for a library to do it for me. I came across *libmcnet*, which seemed to be what I wanted, but all the data it produced was garbled.

Looking over some packet dumps, and referencing it with *wiki.vg*, I discovered that *libmcnet* was giving me *big-endian*. However, my code and computers assume *little-endian*.

**What I have done about it**

After some thinking and looking over the code I thought it easier to write my own parser using some defines from libmcnet (namely include/mcnet/packets.h). So I copied the packets.h and read.h/read.c (both of which were heavily modified) and started recoding it. I did well enough, I think, as my system can successfully parse the server's 0xff (kick) packet during the server ping.

**New problems**

The next hurdle proved to be decrypting the client's data. It doesn't seem to use the same data standards as the server. For instance, the packet id the server transmits is 16 bit while the client's seems to be 8 bit.

*So what I want to know:*

Why does my code work fine on data from the server, but fail miserably when the client sends data? I'm pretty sure that libmcnet's code (on which I based it) is wrong as well.

Can anybody help me make this code work?

Code: http://pastebin.com/jg26yity (I figured this'd be cleaner)

Thank you all for your help!

*I'll add information if anybody requests more...

PS. First question asked here, so my post is a bit messy...

Comment: You should always be converting from network endian to host endian and vice-vera. I can't tell if you doing it, but that's where I'd start.

Comment: @travis My code does convert from big to little endian (and vice-versa).

Comment: I posted this as a answer, but it was deleted because it was late / "not an answer".

BungeeCord these days has limited support for Forge, Waterfall, a fork I believe has better Forge support.

https://github.com/WaterfallMC/Waterfall

I know it's late, but it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, apparently I can't assume a library written to parse the minecraft protocol actually has proper code to read the protocol...
I was digging around and verifying what was read versus manually reading it... Appearantly a byte isn't a byte with minecraft and I thought the library had it covered.